# How safe is using !feof in searching a file?

Tags: c, eof, feof

I read here that `feof` or more precisely using `!feof` in searching for a info in a file is a bad habit.

What I understood is that it's bad because it reads information from the `FILE` pointer before called function or process or something like that.

Wouldn't it be fine to have a `do`/`while` loop with `fscanf` inside and `!feof` as the exit condition?

This is a search function that I did:

```c
typedef struct
{
    char lname[20] , fname[20];
    int nchildren;
}employee;
void searchemployee(char *filename , char *str)
{
    employee e;
    FILE *f;
    int c;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
        printf("file couldn't be loaded\n");
    else {
        c = 0;
        do {
            fscanf(f, "%s %s %d\n", e.fname, e.lname, &e.nchildren);
            if (strcmp(e.fname, str) == 0)
                c = 1;
        } while (c == 0 && !feof(f));
        if (c != 1)
            printf("employee not found\n");
        else
            printf("employee : %s %s| children : %d\n", e.fname, e.lname, e.nchildren);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(f,"%s %s` - what if the first `%s` works, but the second `%s` fails?

Comment: Control the loop with `fscanf`. You should always check that it converted the required items anyway. Aside: remove the newline from the `fscanf` format string. See [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: Just don't think of `feof` as being for asking, "Am I at end of file yet?"  The way you determine whether you're done reading is that your reading function (`fgets`, `fscanf`, `fread`, whatever) returned an error code.  *After* one of those functions returns an error code, if you want to know whether the "error" was due to hitting end-of-file, or for some other reason, you can use `feof` or `ferror` to determine that.

Comment: 3 simple rules: 1. never use `feof()`, 2. do not use `do / while` loops, 3. always test `fscanf()` return value. 4. avoid using `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of the function `feof` specifies whether a previous input operation **has already** encountered the end of the file. This function does not specify whether the next input **will** encounter the end of the file.

The problem with

```
do{
    fscanf(f,"%s %s %d\n",e.fname,e.lname,&e.nchildren);
    if (strcmp(e.fname,str)==0)
        c=1;
}while(c==0 && !feof(f));
```

is that if `fscanf` fails and returns `EOF` due to encountering the end of the file, then it will write nothing to `e.fname`.

If this happens in the first iteration of the loop, then the content of `e.fname` will be indeterminate and the subsequent function call `strcmp(e.fname,str)` will invoke undefined behavior (i.e. your program may crash), unless `e.fname` happens to contain a terminating null character.

If this does not happen in the first iteration, but rather in a subsequent iteration of the loop, then the content of `e.fname` will contain the content of the previous loop iteration, so you will effectively be processing the last successful call of `fscanf` twice.

In this specific case, processing the last successful call of `fscanf` twice is harmless, except for being a slight waste of CPU and memory resources. However, in most other cases, processing the last input twice will result in the program not working as intended.

See the following question for further information:

[Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

If you change the loop to

```
for (;;) {
    fscanf(f,"%s %s %d\n",e.fname,e.lname,&e.nchildren);
    if ( c != 0 || feof(f) )
        break;
    if (strcmp(e.fname,str)==0)
        c=1;
}
```

so that the loop condition is checked in the middle of the loop, then the problem mentioned above will be gone.

However, it is generally better to check the return value of `fscanf` instead of calling `feof`, for example like this:

```
c = 0;

while ( c == 0 && fscanf(f,"%s %s %d\n",e.fname,e.lname,&e.nchildren) == 3 ) {
    if (strcmp(e.fname,str)==0)
        c=1;
}
```

Also, you don't need the flag variable `c`. I suggest that you incorporate the lines

```
if (c!=1)
    printf("emplyee not found\n");
else
    printf("employee : %s %s| children : %d\n",e.fname,e.lname,e.nchildren);
```

partially into the loop, like this:

```
void searchemployee( char *filename, char *str )
{
    employee e;
    FILE *f = NULL;

    //attempt to open file
    f = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( f == NULL )
    {
        printf( "file couldn't be loaded\n" );
        goto cleanup;
    }

    //process one employee record per loop iteration
    while ( fscanf( f, "%s %s %d\n", e.fname, e.lname, &e.nchildren ) == 3 )
    {
        //check whether we found the target record
        if ( strcmp(e.fname,str) == 0 )
        {
            printf(
                "employee : %s %s| children : %d\n",
                e.fname, e.lname, e.nchildren
            );
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    printf( "employee not found.\n");

cleanup:
    if ( f != NULL )
        fclose(f);
}
```

Another issue is that when using `%s` with `scanf` or `fscanf`, you should generally also add a width limit, to prevent a possible [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). For example, if `e.fname` has a size of `100` characters, you should use `%99s` to limit the number of bytes written to `99` plus the terminating null character.

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%s"...)` cannot avoid undefined behavior on longer than expected input.

Comment: @chqrlie: Since OP is not showing us the definition of `employee`, we have no way of knowing the size of `e.fname` and `e.lname`, so I cannot add a width limit.

Comment: Indeed, but you could still mention this problem and for format string could be constructed this way: `snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%%zus%%%zus%%d%%1[\n]", sizeof(e.fname) - 1, sizeof(e.lname) - 1)` but this would probably exceed the OP's skill level.

Comment: @chqrlie: I have now added a paragraph to my answer which mentions this issue.

Comment: @chqrlie Here's a heretical thought: In the grand scheme of things, it's actually fine to use `"%s"` without a size limit.  You should only be using `scanf` and friends *at all* during the first few weeks of your C programming career.  And during those first few weeks, you've arguably got other things to learn before you can even start thinking about buffer overflows.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I don't disagree... First use `scanf` and friends, then learn why they are not your friends :)

Comment: @SteveSummit: *Wondering if there's some kind of 12-step program for unhealthy Stack Overflow addictions*... So do I: I visited S.O. 2648 days out of 2893 since registering, mostly on the [c] tag and it looks like many regulars have found a way to leave for good.

Comment: @chqrlie[(SO and) all the world's a stage, And all the men and women merely Players; They have their exits and their entrances,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_world%27s_a_stage).

Comment: @chqrlie i just added the structure to the code.
suppose i didn't know the size of e.fname like if i used 'char* fname' in the struct how would i go about the preventing buffer overflow

Comment: @ayoubhmani: if the structure only has a pointer for `fname`, you must either have a separate variable with the size of the array it points to or it might be that `fname` is pointing to an allocated string that should be reallocated to change the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `feof` asks the question “Was end-of-file or an error encountered in a **previous** operation on this stream?”

If you use `feof` to answer that question, that is fine. But, you use `feof` to expect that your **next** operation **will** read data from the file, that is wrong. The previous operation might have ended just **before** the end of the file, so `feof` says “no,” but there is nothing left in the file to read.

The file/stream functions in the standard C library are designed to tell you when they failed because end-of-file was reached. You should use the return value (or other indication) provided by each function to test for a problem:

```
if (3 != fscanf(f, "%s %s %d\n", e.fname, e.lname, &e.nchildren))
{
    // Handle fact that fscanf did not read and convert 3 values.
}

int x = getchar();
if (x == EOF)
{
    // Handle fact that fscanf did not read and convert 3 values.
}
```

Note that calling `fscanf` and then `feof` will tell if `fscanf` encountered end-of-file or an input error, but it will not tell you whether `fscanf` read **some** input and assigned **some** values but then encountered end-of-file and did not finish. If you are reading only one thing, you might get away with `fscanf` followed by `feof`, but a more sophisticated program may need to distinguish partial inputs.